# A crew of an $8$ oar boat has to be chosen out of $11$ people, five of whom can row on stroke side only, four on the bow side only

Tags: combinatorics

A crew of an $8$ oar boat has to be chosen out of $11$ people, five of whom can row on stroke side only, four on the bow side only, and the remaining two on the either side. How many different selections can be made?

---

As a crew of $8$ people is to be selected, $4$ must be on the stroke side and $4$ must be on the bow side.

As $7$ people can row on stroke side and $6$ people can row on the bow side.

So total selections are $\binom{7}{4}\times\binom{6}{4}=525$ but the answer given is $145$, I do not know where i have gone wrong.

Comment: Your count doesn't work...if, say, you've used the two bimodal folk on one side then they aren't available on the other.  I think it's easiest to first assign (or not) the bimodal folk, and then populate the remaining slots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go case by case according to where the bimodal folk are assigned (if they are assigned).  Notation:  $(a,b)$ means that $a$ of the flexible rowers are on the left and $b$ are on the right.

Case I.  we use $2$ of them.

Ia.  $(2,0)$.  Then we get $\binom 52 \times \binom 44=10$

Ib.  $(0,2)$.  then we get $\binom 54 \times \binom 42 = 30$

Ic.  $(1,1)$.  then we get $\binom 53\times \binom 43= 40$

Case II.  we use $1$ of them.

IIa. $(1,0)$   We get $\binom 53\times \binom 44=10$

IIb.  $(0,1)$  We get $\binom 54 \times \binom 43=20$

Note:  there are two ways to choose the flexible man so case II yields $60$ combinations all in all.

Case III.  we use $0$ of them.  we get $\binom 54\times \binom 44=5$

Combining we get a total of $\fbox {145}$

Comment: In Ic., aren't there two ways of assigning the bimodal folk, giving a total of $80$ and a final total of $185$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  The way I read the problem, we are just asking for the number of possible crews.  Accordingly, it doesn't matter if Bob is on the left, and Fred on the right so long as both are on the team.

Comment: On rereading the question, I agree with your interpretation.  Otherwise, we would presumably have to account for the positions on each side.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  Agreed.